# Cassandra connection has been closed error when querying via Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I'm trying to access remote Cassandra using Spark in Java. However, when I'm trying to execute an aggregation function (count), the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.1.103:9042] Connection has been closed
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException.copy(TransportException.java:38)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException.copy(TransportException.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
```

I already set the timeout in the Cassandra.yml to big value.
Here is my code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setAppName("Test");
conf.setMaster("local[*]");
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "host");
Spark app = new Spark(conf);
app.run();
.
.
.
CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(sc.getConf());
// Prepare the schema
try (Session session = connector.openSession()) {
session.execute("USE keyspace0");
ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM table0");
```

Comment: what code are you running?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: I would guess your try block isn't doing what you suspect and the connection is closed by the time you perform the query